# UIScrollview large contentsize

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to create a big UIview ( 3600 X 4600 ) and scroll it via UIScrollView.

```
CGRect contentViewFrame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 3600, 4600);
UIView *cView=[[ContentView alloc]initWithFrame:contentViewFrame];
self.contentView=cView;

[self.scrollView addSubview:cView];
self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(3600, 4600);
```

But I have one problem. When I run my app on simulator everything is ok! But when I run the app on my iPhone and try to zoom out to see a whole view ( 3600 X 4600 ) my app crashes and iPhone resprings. It seems like my view ( 3600 X 4600 ) is to big and iPhone can't show me view in full size. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When app crashes what is the logged in your console?

Comment: it doesn't just crash, it respring my iPhone immediately. it happens when I zoom out and see about 80% of whole view in scrollView. And it doesn't log anything just respring and that's all.

Comment: Do you get didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Comment: is ur device jailborken ?

Comment: No, I don't get didRecieveMemoryWarning. Yes, My iPhone is jailborken.

Comment: try remove all application from background and restart app

Comment: i've just tried but it crashes again.

Comment: in Apple's official documenation that UIImageView should not have images with more than 1024x1024 pixels. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440864/uiimage-with-large-image-size-memory-problem-crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using a CATiledLayer as your view layer. This way you'll minimise the amount if memory your view uses when zoomed.